# http get response to same uri means same format in response

Tags: http, http-headers, httprequest, httpresponse, http-get

I have a question regarding the response to a HTTP request.

**My question is**

The representations present in responses to `GET requests` on the same URI should always have the same format, and why.

I thought that the server might change the content associated to that URI, or that the client making the request might change the accept header in the request, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm a little unsure what you're asking. You're asking if a server will always return a `200` / `404` or similar when you make a `GET` request?

Comment: No i'm asking about the format of the representations present in responses

Answer (score 0):

The format may changed based on Content-Encoding, Content-Disposition, and a lot of other things. Compression for example may be used (but that's not the final format, just the transport format). The page may contain dynamic content, based on your current user session (so based on your cookies, for example).

The server response would usually contain a `Vary` header which clearly states, for your browser, the request headers that may influence the content of the page.

For example you may have a `Vary: cookie` which means that if the browser requested this page without a cookie, and that later you have a cookie for this website, then the page content should not be loaded from the browser cache and a new request should be made.

So your first sentence is wrong, or too simple. Request headers and Response headers can contain informations on validity of the message, how to store it, when to ask for changes, or what headers may alter the message content.